# Could not find file in declared path

Tags: c#, winforms

*C#, WFA, using .NET 4.5 platform,*

I dropped textBox1 (firstname), textBox2 (lastname), pictureBox1 (employee phot), button2 (browse), and button1 (save) to insert new employees.

button2 -> must browse image and display in pictureBox1,

button1 -> must save the image, which was browsed by button2 and is in display by pictureBox1, [**to this table in localhost.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPKOm.png)

After I run the program, [**I GET THIS ERROR (file could not be found.)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX6SB.png)

(I don't get any error on browsing alone though)

I just want answers that contain codes to fix this WFA. Just want to be sure I'm crystal clear on this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=randomcompany;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Browse button
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
                dlg.Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*";
                dlg.Title = "Select Employee Picture";
                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
                    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Save button
        {

            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                string path = pictureBox1.Image.ToString();
                Byte[] imagedata = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employees (EmployeeFirstname, EmployeeLastname, EmployeePhoto) VALUES (@item1,@item2,@img", cnn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item1", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item2", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", imagedata);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: u got error while browsing image or saving ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that this:

```
string path = pictureBox1.Image.ToString();
```

does not return a path. Store the path when you get it in a class field. Let's name it `_path`:

```
private string _path;
```

and then let's set it when you get the file name:

```
_path = dlg.FileName;
```

and then just use it here:

```
Byte[] imagedata = File.ReadAllBytes(_path);
```

Here is the full code modified:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string _path;

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=randomcompany;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Browse button
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
                dlg.Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*";
                dlg.Title = "Select Employee Picture";
                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
                    _path = dlg.FileName;
                    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Save button
        {

            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                Byte[] imagedata = File.ReadAllBytes(_path);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employees (EmployeeFirstname, EmployeeLastname, EmployeePhoto) VALUES (@item1,@item2,@img", cnn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item1", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item2", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", imagedata);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you try to get image file path from your image here:

```
string path = pictureBox1.Image.ToString();
```

you actually get the name of Image type (System.Drawing.Bitmap)

You need to keep path to image file after selecting it in dialog. You can do it like this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
pictureBox1.Tag = dlg.FileName;
```

Then you need to read this name like this:

```
string path = pictureBox1.Tag as string;
```

Comment: You should add line: pictureBox1.Tag = dlg.FileName; to button2_Click handler and modify assignment of path variable to: string path = pictureBox1.Tag as string; in button1_Click handler

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong property to get the image path. You should you 
[PictureBox.ImageLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation.aspx) property of picture box to get the exact location of image.

Modify this part

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Save button
    {

        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            string path = pictureBox1.ImageLocation; // this will work
            string path = pictureBox1.Image.ToString(); // here error comes
            Byte[] imagedata = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employees (EmployeeFirstname, EmployeeLastname, EmployeePhoto) VALUES (@item1,@item2,@img", cnn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item1", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item2", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", imagedata);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: it means picture is not present in the picture box.